# Live website to video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have a website which shows a slideshow of pictures using JS.

The pictures objects are coming from a web service and are being updated from time to time.

In few days, I doing a test with a potential client to present the pictures slideshow on his big LED screen.

He's using BSPlayer for the content on screen, an able to present a website, but it will never be a clean full screen (the X button and such will always be presents).

He's the most comfort with presenting a video rather than a website.

One of my ideas of solutions was to check if there is a way to stream a content of a website.

Googling it got me to a solution combined `ImageMagic` and `FFMPEG` which you can read about [here](http://www.itforeveryone.co.uk/image-to-video.html)

My problem is that this solution only creates a slide show out of static pictures - which I can do, but i'm losing the dynamic part of my live slideshow.

Is there a tool for capturing websites and converting them into a stream of videos?

Or maybe a workaround to achieve the same functionality ?

Comment: you want a screen capture program for your operating system perhaps

Comment: Ideali a screen capture of a rendered website :) not sure if it is possible